# Capturing the input stream as a user types

Tags: c++, input, stdin, iostream, real-time

I am working on a C++ based command line tool and I want to capture the user's keystrokes in real-time without requiring them to hit `Return` to commit the input. I can't seem to find an iostream call to support this kind of behavior but I recall from my college years that it can be done. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is outside of the C++ spec and requires OS specific calls.  On Posix, you do this by enabling raw or cbreak mode instead of cooked mode.

The easiest way to enable this is via [curses](http://linux.die.net/man/3/raw).